# understanding HashMap<Integer, Object>(3)

Tags: java, hashmap

This maybe due to my lack of Java experience, but I set this `hashmap` to allow 3(or 4) entries into it like this:

```
 Map<Integer, Object> myAwesomeCache = new HashMap<Integer, Object>(3);
 for (int i = 0; i < 222; i++)
 {
      myAwesomeCache.put(i, "dd");
 }
```

However, my loop which is set to 222 continues to populate it until there are 222 entries in there. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: What is so difficult to look into the JavaDoc? It's the 'initialCapacity' http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

The value you are passing is not a maximum, it's just the starting size.

Comment: what is the benefit of setting a starting size ? what are they trying to achieve?

Comment: if you are going to add a lot (several millions) of elements sequentially it has to resize very often. by setting the initial size as high as the size it's going to be after adding, you avoid all the resizing, which takes a lot of time with that many elements.